# determine selector validity

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a function like this:

```
function parseValue(value, defaultValue) {
    if ($.isFunction(value))
        return value();

    if (!value)
        return defaultValue;

    if ($(value).size() > 0)
        return $(value).val();

    return value;
};
```

`value` can be a function, a "value", or a jquery selector.  My problem is how do I determine that the selector is valid (finds a control).

for example, when `value` equals 56.87 `$(value).size() > 0` evaluates to true.  I want it to be false.  Even if something like `#invalidcontrolid` was passed in, if it doesn't actually exist on the page, I want to get false back so I can return the value.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.size()` is just a wrapper method for `.length` property. So this should (and does) work:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/EawgE/

You should check within your `parseValue` method if `value` actually is a number. If so, just return `false` or whatever but don't pass it into the jQuery constructor.

```
if( typeof value === 'number' ) {}
```

or

```
if( $.type(value) === 'number' ) {}
```

Example:

```
function parseValue(value, defaultValue) {
    if ($.isFunction(value))
        return value();

    if ( $.type(value) === 'number' )
        return value; // ?

    if ( $.type(value) === 'string' && $(value).length )
        return $(value).val();

    return defaultValue;
};
```

Comment: Works like a champ.  Thanks jAndy.